# SetProperty doesn't update all file properties on site

Tags: c#, sharepoint

On a SharePoint 2010 site, I have an ItemAdded event receiver which detects pages added to the Pages library, fills it with information from a file, and from that information sets some custom columns so that the pages can be searched based on their contents. The portion of the function that sets the columns is similar to this:

```
page.SetProperty("Column1", ExistsOrEmpty("Property1", dictionary));
page.SetProperty("Column2", ExistsOrEmpty("Property2", dictionary));
...
page.Update();
```

Where `page` is of type `SPFile` and is the page that has been added to the library. `ExistsOrEmpty` is a function I wrote to prevent a KeyNotFound exception:

```
private static string ExistsOrEmpty(string key, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    try
    {
        return dict[key];
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

My issue is that there is one column in particular, Description, that isn't updated on the site, even though the rest are updated without any problems. Here are the steps I've taken to debug this code when stepping through line by line:

1. I make sure `ExistsOrEmpty("Description", dict)` returns the correct value, which it does.
2. I execute `page.SetProperty("Description", ExistsOrEmpty("Description", dict))`, along with all of the other properties I wish to set. All of the properties I update are single-line strings.
3. I update the page using `page.Update()`.
4. I check the page's properties using `page.GetProperty` to confirm that all properties have been updated correctly, which they have.
5. I finish debugging and check the page's properties on the SharePoint site itself using View Properties. All the properties I've set *except the Description* have been updated.

I can't imagine why this one column wouldn't update when the others have updated without a problem. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** <s>I've done some tweaking to try to fix this issue, and it has begun happening for multiple other columns as well. I noticed that, for the other columns, the error occurs where the column name used to have a space and I removed it. I've made sure to update my code to account for these changes, and my debugger still shows the columns as being updated, but the UI does not reflect these changes.</s> Using internal names rather than display names fixed this problem, but not the main problem I'm having with the Description.

Comment: Have you tried editing the description via the UI, Is this possible? Have you tried editing the description via powershell? Is this possible?

Comment: I've tried editing via the UI, and this hasn't caused any problems. I don't have experience using PowerShell to work with SharePoint, so I haven't tried that. The issue is that while it's possible to edit via the UI, the library I'm working with will have hundreds of pages, so the only practical way to update the columns is to do so automatically.

Comment: Are you using internal column names or display names?

Comment: I've been using display names. Regarding my edit, I changed the display names of the columns and changed my code to match the new display names.

Comment: Have you tried using the internal names?

Comment: Using the internal names fixed the problem with the columns that formerly had spaces in their display names, but still hasn't fixed the issue with the Description. In my code, I changed `page.SetProperty("Description"...` to `page.SetProperty("Description0"...` (the internal name I found by checking SPDesigner), and got the same problem: the code shows the column has updated, but the UI doesn't show this.

Comment: Something sounds suspicious about that internal field name

Comment: I agree, but I used [this other method](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column) to find the internal name and confirmed that it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this please.

Your SPFile object should have an SPListItem object on it.

it will be something like `page.item["Description"] = "desc"`

Then call an update.

Cheers
Truez